# How to partially synchronize two branches?

Tags: git

I have a branch 'static-analysis', which is some analysis scripts on top of the main branch. Once in a while, I rebase it onto the latest main, rerun the scripts, find some bugs, and fix them.

To patch the bugfix onto the main branch **without copying the analysis scripts**, I can think of two choices, neither being perfect: 1) create a merge request "static-analysis -> main", then manually cherry-pick away the commits concerning the analysis scripts; 2) create a temporary branch "bugfix" from "static-analysis", locally rebase it and remove the commits concerning the analysis scripts, then create a merge request "bugfix -> main".

I'd like to ask if there's a best practice for this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply rebase/reorder the commits, then go with the PR.... something like this:

```
* static-analysis commit 2 (HEAD -> static-analysis)
* static-analysis commit 1
* main branch commit 3 (main)
* main branch commit 2
* main branch commit 1
```

So, you run your scripts, find a few things to fix, fix it, commit:

```
* some fixes for main (HEAD -> static-analysis)
* static-analysis commit 2
* static-analysis commit 1
* main branch commit 3 (main)
* main branch commit 2
* main branch commit 1
```

So, at this point, I would do a rebase to reorder the commits in `static-analysis`

```
git rebase -i main
```

Reorder the 3 commits in the list so that the first one to be applied is the fix for main. After rebase is done, you get this:

```
* static-analysis commit 2 (HEAD -> static-analysis)
* static-analysis commit 1
* some fixes for main
* main branch commit 3 (main)
* main branch commit 2
* main branch commit 1
```

At this point, you can create a branch on the fixes commit and create a PR just for it.